# How to get the padding to change on the FAB when docked on bottom app bar?

Tags: dart, flutter, floating-action-button, textedit, bottomappbar

The problem is that when the `FAB` is docked onto the `BottomAppBar`, and then the keyboard is called, the `FAB` padding resize doesn't correctly align above the keyboard for the user to press.

Here is what is actually occurring...

[image]

A quick example of the scaffold that reproduces the error;

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.lightbulb_outline,
            color: Colors.deepPurple,
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: TextField(),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
);
```

Comment: can you post your `scaffold`?

Comment: I've added a snippet of a `scaffold` that reproduces the error